# Change database files location in MySQL administrator?

Tags: mysql

I would like to change the database files location of MySQL administrator to another drive of my computer.  (I run Windows XP SP2 and MySQL Administrator 1.2.8.)

--Under the startup variable --> General Parameters --> I changed `Data directory:` from  `C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.0/data` to `D:/.....`, but after I stopped the service and restarted it, the following error appeared:

```
Could not re-connect to the MySQL Server.
Server could not be started.

Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
```

Has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Normally it works like this:

1. shut down MySQL
2. change the `[mysqld]` and `[mysqld_safe]` `datadir` variable in the MySQL configuration
3. change the `basedir` variable in the same section.
4. move the location over
5. restart MySQL

If that doesn't work I have no idea.  On linux you can try to move the socket to a new location too, but that shouldn't affect windows.  Alternatively you can use a symbolic link on *nix what most people do I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your help Armin Ronacher.... i added one line in my.ini file is **[mysql_safe]
datadir=D:/_sql** And now it is work. I am a new in this website, i am very appreciated with all of your help. I'm gonna register my name in here too.

Answer (score 9):

In Windows

1. Navigate to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.4\` and locate the `my.ini` file
2. Find the SERVER SECTION and go to approx line 76 and modify the **datadir** line to where you want your MySQL application data to be stored
3. Now navigate to `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.4\data\` and copy and paste the mysql folder into your new location.
4. Restart the MySQL Server in *Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Service*

Comment: It is necessary to add access of NETWORK SERVICE account to the folder as well

Answer (score 0):

You also have to manually modify mysql's configuration (usually my.conf)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Administrator cannot be used for tasks like this. It is merely a tool for looking at  MySQL servers, despite its name. Relocating data is described in many MySQL tutorials and in the manual IIRC. But basically it's just moving the data to a new location while the server is shut down and then correcting the paths in the servers config file.
After that you should be able to restart the server and connect MySQL Administrator to it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you give the Network Service Full permissions in the security tab of Windows Explorer options. If the server can't read/write etc. to the selected folder the service will either not start or it will attempt a start and shut right down.